# goapp test not working,getting error "GOPATH must be absolute" while it is absolute

Tags: google-app-engine, go, testing, gopath

I'm tying to write tests for my google cloud app. I read the documents and it seems the only way to run the test locally is the running the command `goapp test` in the test package directory. But when I run the command I get the error `go: GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "".`

I'm pretty sure my GOPATH is set absolutely. Here are the results when I run the command `go env | grep GOPATH`:

`GOPATH=":/home/mohammad/go:/home/mohammad/go/src/gitlab.com/gc-auth"`

Also getting the same output when I run `echo $GOPATH`.

Any help is appreciated.

PS: I have ubuntu 18.04 and my go version is 1.10.4

results of `gcloud version`:

`Google Cloud SDK 228.0.0
app-engine-go 
app-engine-python 1.9.80
bq 2.0.39
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.0.2
core 2018.12.07
gsutil 4.34`

Comment: Your GOPATH is simply wrong. It should probably be just "/home/mohammad/go".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GOPATH=":/home/mohammad/go:/home/mohammad/go/src/gitlab.com/gc-auth"
```

The GOPATH starts with an empty path (which is technically relative), followed by two absolute paths. The error message is correct.